# Word embedding Visualization using TSNE not clear

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have downloaded pre-trained model of word embeddings from [Word Embeddings by M. Baroni et al.](http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/composes/semantic-vectors.html) 
I want to visualize embeddings of words present in sentences. I have two sentences:

```
sentence1 = "Four people died in an accident."

sentence2 = "4 men are dead from a collision"
```

I have function to load the embeddings file from above link:

```
def load_data(FileName = './EN-wform.w.5.cbow.neg10.400.subsmpl.txt'):

    embeddings = {}
    file = open(FileName,'r')
    i = 0
    print "Loading word embeddings first time"
    for line in file:
        # print line

        tokens = line.split('\t')

        #since each line's last token content '\n'
        # we need to remove that
        tokens[-1] = tokens[-1].strip()

        #each line has 400 tokens
        for i in xrange(1, len(tokens)):
            tokens[i] = float(tokens[i])

        embeddings[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:-1]
    print "finished"
    return embeddings

e = load_data()
```

From both the sentences, I compute **lemmas** of words and **ignore stopwords and punctuations**, so now my sentences becomes:

```
sentence1 = ['Four', 'people', 'died', 'accident']
sentence2 = ['4', 'men', 'dead', 'collision']
```

Now, when I try to visualize the embeddings using TSNE(t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding), I first store labels and tokens for each sentence:

```
#for sentence store labels and embeddings in list
# tokens contains vector of 400 dimensions for each label
labels1 = []
tokens1 = []
for i in sentence1:
    if i in e:
        labels1.append(i)
        tokens1.append(e[i])
    else:
        print i

labels2 = []
tokens2 = []
for i in sentence2:
    if i in e:
        labels2.append(i)
        tokens2.append(e[i])
    else:
        print i
```

## For TSNE

```
tsne_model = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='random', n_iter=2000, random_state=23)
# fit transform for tokens of both sentences
new_values = tsne_model.fit_transform(tokens1)
new_values1 = tsne_model.fit_transform(tokens2)

#Plot values
x = []
y = []
x1 = []
y1 = []

for value in new_values:
    x.append(value[0])
    y.append(value[1])

for value in new_values1:
    x1.append(value[0])
    y1.append(value[1])


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10)) 

for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i],y[i])
    plt.annotate(labels[i],
                 xy=(x[i], y[i]),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')

for i in range(len(x1)):
    plt.scatter(x1[i],y1[i])
    plt.annotate(labels[i],
                 xy=(x1[i], y1[i]),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of labels in 2-dimension]

My **question** is that, why synonyms words such as "collision" and "accident", "people" and "people" have different co-ordinates? if words are same/synonyms, shouldn't they be closer?

distances = euclidean_distances(tokens1)
  # returns shape (8,8)

Answer (score 1):

From the [TSNE-documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html):

> t-SNE has a cost function that is not convex, i.e. with different initializations we can get different results.

Which means you aren't guaranteed to get the same coordinates when performing a dimensionality reduction of the word embeddings.

To solve this, perform the fit_transform once instead of twice, by joining your sentences:

```
sentence1 = ['Four', 'people', 'died', 'accident']
sentence2 = ['4', 'men', 'dead', 'collision']
sentences = list(set(sentence1)| set(sentence2))
```

EDIT: There is also a bug in your code, you're plotting labels from the wrong list.

Comment: I did like this, but synonyms are not closer to each other. Do you know Word Embeddings by  Baroni el. al? Is there any other to solve embeddings of sentences?

Comment: @Lucky Try using the euclidian_distances function in sk_learn on the embeddings and see if the distances between the words make sense.

Comment: you mean when i get co-ordinates from TSNE, I should compute euclidean distance between each term and see whether synonyms has minimum distance or not?

Comment: @Lucky No, compute the euclidian distances before TSNE and print the distance matrix.

Comment: i did that, and got array of (8,8). I used that distance matrix for model.fit, when I plot i don't see any difference. I have added that line in post. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Lucky There is a bug in your code, please see my edit.

Comment: its correct, but i forget to paste in post. you can check full code here : [TSNE Embedding](https://gist.github.com/rameshjesswani/7c9c94ae4f1bbce6677c62de9cbc8c8a)